# Modify php date and time to week days during office hours PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I have a PHP function that modifies the current date time and adds 2 weeks while adding an entry to the database and sending an email to user after the 2 week period expires the function will overwrite the entry and leave that table entry open for the next user.

```
public function UpdateDemos(){
        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "yearbook_hub_accounts";
        $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name", OBJECT );

        foreach ($results as $account){
            if($account->requested){
                $requestDate = new DateTime($account->requested);
                $requestDateExpires = $requestDate->modify("+2 weeks");
                $todaysDate = new DateTime();

                if($requestDateExpires->getTimestamp() < $todaysDate->getTimestamp()){
                    self::send_notification_email($account);
                    $wpdb->update($table_name, ['requested' => null, 'email' => null, 'password' => self::generatePassword()], ['id' => $account->id]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Externally from this function, we need to update the passwords with a third party and the problem with this is due to the function being set to +2weeks these password resets could be any time day or night.

i would really like this function to modify date +2 weeks between office hours so the question would which would be the best route do i modify the + 2weeks

or do i a adjust

```
$requestDateExpires->getTimestamp() < $todaysDate->getTimestamp()
```

to only reset 9-5 monday to friday.

1st attempt was to use something like a switch case to get the correct day intervals

```
$today = date("D");
switch($today){
    case "Mon":
    case "Tue":
    case "Wed":
    case "Thurs":
    case "Fri":
        $days = 14;
        break;
    case "Sat":
        $days = 16;
        break;
    case "Sun":
        $days = 15;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: What are the exact rules? When +2 weeks falls on a weekend or outside of business hours, what do you want to happen instead? Also, what have you tried to solve this?

Comment: the rules would be if the reset is outside of office hours reset the next business day at 9am

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard to achieve. You take the date, identify the day of the week and the time. If it's not within the business hours, you move it to the next work day at 9. Any particular part of that process you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for...

```
<?php

// first identify your work days
// 1 = monday, 2 = tuesday, 7 = sunday
$office_days    = array(
        1, //monday
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
);
// set the office hours
$day_start      = "09:00:00";
$day_end        = "17:00:00";

// change the request date to test different scenarios

$request_date   = new dateTime("2021-08-14 18:32:10.000");

// use the N dateTime::format to identify if the request date is an work day
if(!in_array( $request_date->format('N'),$office_days)) { // we could go straight to the while loop, but you want set it to 9am on the next work day if it's outside normal work days
        while(!in_array( $request_date->format('N'),$office_days)) {
                $request_date->modify('+1 day');
        }
        $request_date->setTime(9,0,0); //hour,minute,second
}

echo "Request date: " . $request_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```